# Why are quotient sets (types) called quotients -- are they the inverse of some product?

Tags: set-theory, terminology, type-theory

There seems to be a beautiful relation between natural numbers and sets (and types),
as in the size of a discriminate union, cartesian product, and function type,
is described by the sum, product, exponential of the sizes of the components. (As I learned from type theory). This also makes it easy to see why the symbols + and x are used for discriminate union and cartesian product (sum type and product type).

$$
\forall A, B, C : \text{sets} \\
A + B = C ~ \implies ~ |A| + |B| = |C|\\
A \times B = C ~ \implies ~ |A| \times |B| = |C|\\
A → B = C ~ \implies ~~~~~~~~ |B|^{|A|} = |C|
$$

However, why are quotient sets (and quotient types) called *quotients* and use the symbol $/$?

That does not seem to make sense to me. At the very least, to deserve the name quotient, I would expect them to somehow be the inverse of some product. I first thought they should be the inverse of the cartesian product, I tried to google this, but I cannot find anything. Is there some relation between quotient (sets) and (cartesian) products, that I am missing?

Comment: If you consider quotients of groups, there is a convincing [argument](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_Quotient_Group) showing why the notation makes sense.

Comment: In the spirit of @Aurelio's answer, perhaps the next best thing to a product is a bundle; given groups $H \le G$, we have the bundle $G \to G/H$ with fibres $H$.  (Although there are set maps $G \cong H \times G/H$, they respect no interesting structure in general, even if $H$ is normal.)  A general quotient of set $X$ by equivalence relation $\sim$ doesn't admit $X \cong X/{\sim} \times \text?$ in any reasonable sense, even as sets, but we still have the projection $X \to X/{\sim}$.

Answer (score 1):

Really this is the wrong forum for your question. Anyway, here is an analogy.

Suppose you have many cookies, say 24 of them, and you want to share them with two of your friends.  You may believe in equity, and you want some of the cookies, and to give one person more than another may be socially awkward, so you want to arrange the cookies into piles or boxes so that you and your friends can check that they each have the same number. If the cookies are of different sorts, they might check that each person got the right quantity of each sort (one may prefer oatmeal to ginger and the other may have the opposite preference, say).

You arrange the cookies into three boxes, and (if I did the arithmetic right) each box got eight cookies.  (This assumes none ate cookies during the process.)  In arithmetic, the three is the dividend, and the eight is the quotient.

If you have one or three or five friends, you can do this process again with similar outcomes, and everyone gets an equal number of cookies in their box.  If you have four friends though, there is a problem: five does not divide 24 evenly. You have to put four in each box ,and you have a remainder of four left over.  For equal division, you may need another method, like breaking cookies.  Or you can put the remainder in its own box for later processing.

The idea is to split up some space into pieces so that you can deal with the collections in some way. Oddly, the three boxes are consider the quotient space, and one thinks about how the groups relate to one another.  It may be the remainder box is important to the quotient space.  Just as important are the properties that are preserved as well as those that are dropped in passing to the quotient.  The idea is not that the quotient is an inverse, but that it is a result of something that is complementary to something like Cartesian product.

Gerhard "Can I Have The Leftovers?" Paseman, 2020.06.04.